# Text overflows past container and loses its original formatting

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text inside a container. The value of the text itself is formatted but when I add it to the block the format is condensed and it overflows past the box.

How can I keep the format of the text as well as add a scrollbar in the container to keep it from overflowing?

[image]

The span value as shown escapes the container but if you look above in the grey area the value itself is formatted correctly upon inspection

[image]

Snippet:

```css
.container-card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span style="overflow: scroll !important;">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: add the `overflow: scroll` to the `.container-card` not the `span`.

Comment: First of all, you can't keep the formatted markup as you've written it, browser will parse HTML and display it as plain text. Check here if you want to display it as code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789148/how-to-display-html-code-in-a-html-page-in-a-formatted-manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `overflow-y` for the container not the `span`, and use `<pre>`  to display formatted code :

```css
.container {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<pre>
DECLARE N INTEGER;
 SET N = 1;
 FOR C 
 AS C_USR_MISE_A_JOUR 
    CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT USR_ID, USR_NOM
       FROM   T_UTILISATEUR_USR
       ORDER  BY USR_ID
    FOR UPDATE OF USR_NOM
 DO
    IF MOD(N, 2) = 0
    THEN
       UPDATE T_UTILISATEUR_USR
       
DECLARE N INTEGER;
 SET N = 1;
 FOR C 
 AS C_USR_MISE_A_JOUR 
    CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT USR_ID, USR_NOM
       FROM   T_UTILISATEUR_USR
       ORDER  BY USR_ID
    FOR UPDATE OF USR_NOM
 DO
    IF MOD(N, 2) = 0
    THEN
       UPDATE T_UTILISATEUR_USR

DECLARE N INTEGER;
 SET N = 1;
 FOR C 
 AS C_USR_MISE_A_JOUR 
    CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT USR_ID, USR_NOM
       FROM   T_UTILISATEUR_USR
       ORDER  BY USR_ID
    FOR UPDATE OF USR_NOM
 DO
    IF MOD(N, 2) = 0
    THEN
       UPDATE T_UTILISATEUR_USR
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pre` to keep the formatting and then set the `overflow` to `scroll`

I made a [codepen example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLZbGL)

The first block of lorem ipsum is styled, the next is default `pre` to show how it looks without any styling.

Is this what you want?